# Help about 4shared's search

Tags: search

My question is about 4shared. I'm looking for a way to find videos, which are not listed, but which, however, are available and visible, and this for all, because they are public videos.

Could someone help me to find these videos more easily, please? Thank you.

I am looking for videos with the word "wedgie" in the title.